# COUNT + JOIN COM DIFICULDADE NO RESULTADO

Tags: firebird, count, inner-join

Estou precisando chegar em dois resultados... 
Tenho uma tabela com um total de 102 motoristas e uma outra tabela onde consta a data que ele saiu pra fazer entregas e outra com a data de chegada...

**Preciso saber quais motoristas estão nas ruas e quais estão de folga.**

O problema é que quando faço um join para as tabelas o resultado não vem como esperado...

Exemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT ('MOTORISTAS.CODIGO') 
FROM
MOTORISTAS 
WHERE 
MOTORISTAS.SITUACAO = 'A' AND
MOTORISTAS.OBS LIKE '%BAÚ%' AND
MOTORISTAS.CODIGO IN (SELECT VIAGENS.ID_MOTORISTA
            FROM VIAGENS 
            WHERE VIAGENS.ID_MOTORISTA <> 0)

ou este ...
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT MOTORISTAS.CODIGO) 
FROM
MOTORISTAS INNER JOIN VIAGENS ON MOTORISTAS.CODIGO = VIAGENS.ID_MOTORISTA
WHERE 
MOTORISTAS.SITUACAO = 'A' AND
MOTORISTAS.OBS LIKE '%BAÚ%' AND
VIAGENS.ID_MOTORISTA <> 0
```

Ambos apresentam um resultado de `42`

Comment: Qual o seu SGBD? O que diz se ele está em viagem?

Comment: as tabelas estão no Firebird

Comment: Objetivo é duas respostas ,,um qtos motoristas estão em viagem e quantos motoristas estão em casa

Comment: Tá, mas você não respondeu o que eu perguntei: Como você sabe se ele está em viagem? A viagem tem um status ou você apenas deleta ele quando ele termina uma? E qual o vínculo entre as tabelas? A tabela motorista tem um `id_motorista`?

Comment: Ops , sim, a tabela Viagens tem duas colunas para esse fim, uma dta de saido *qdo ele sai pra viajar e outra com dta chegada... qdo ele finaliza essa viagem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente utilizar este SQL, faça as modificações necessárias de acordo com seus campos:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       COUNT(IIF(((V.DATA_SAIDA IS NOT NULL)AND(V.DATA_CHEGADA IS NULL)AND(V.ID_MOTORISTA IS NOT NULL))
                ,1
                ,NULL)) AS EM_VIAGEM
      ,COUNT(IIF(((V.DATA_SAIDA IS NULL)OR(V.DATA_CHEGADA IS NOT NULL))
                ,1
                ,NULL)) AS PARADOS
  FROM      MOTORISTAS M
  LEFT JOIN VIAGENS    V ON V.ID_MOTORISTA = M.CODIGO
 WHERE M.SITUACAO = 'A' 
   AND M.OBS      LIKE '%BAÚ%'
```

Comment: Obrigado @Matheus Ribeiro

Comment: De nada, isso resolveu seu problema?

Comment: @VictorAndrade Se minha resposta resolveu seu problema, favor marcá-la como aceita ou me de um feedback para te ajudar!